# How to open directories in geany IDE?

Tags: 12.04, application-development, eclipse, ide, geany

I have a directory already created which has sub-directories in it, it was created by Eclipse IDE. And now, I'm willing to continue developing the same project using a different IDE -  Geany IDE.

But, It seems that Geany doesn't open directories, it only opens files, is that true?
Because it'd be really hard to develop with it. I'll have to edit a file, close it and open another file, which is not effective when navigating between different files.

**What I tried to open a directory:**
I opened Geany, went to Project->open->/var/www/public_html/[ProjectName], then clicked enter/open. But it didn't work as expected, clicking open/enter only shows the project files in the file browser.
I'm assuming that I have to create a special file(*.geany or something) and put it in the project root folder to make it a valid Geany project, is that true? if so, then how can I create such a file.

**Extra Information:**
I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, picked up Geany from software center, which I think is the latest version.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create a new Geany project (Project > New) and set the directory to where your project files are.

I think you are mistaking the *'Documents'* tab seen in the sidebar for the *'File Browser'*. To see the File Browser go to *Tools > Plugins* and enable tick/check the *File Browser* plugin.

Edit:
The **Filename** field creates the Geany project file (ProjectName.geany). The **Base Path** is used to run the Build menu commands (for compiling etc).

It is recommended to keep all of your files in the same directory created in the **Filename** field.

Comment: For the first part(creating a project). I'm allowed to choose a filename and base path. Which one of them is used to get my project's files? since both of them has the same values.

Comment: And for the second part, I enabled file browsing. but how can I display it in the GUI? the browser doesn't seem to show up, unless I have to open a project first?

Comment: When you enable the File browser plugin a 'Files' tab appears in the sidebar. You can show/hide the sidebar from the *View > Show Sidebar* menu. I have updated my original post to explain the difference between the filename and base path paths. Also you might want to check out http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#new-project

Comment: The file browser plugin was the answer for me. Nice little add-on

Comment: This doesn't work. Enabling those plugins shows no noticeable change. Using an existing base directory doesn't show any existing files.

Comment: Me too @henrywright. Now I wish I could find a tree view!

Comment: For the others that think they didn't make it working like I though: after you enable the "file browser plugin", you will see a "Files" tab. Just underneath it there is a home sign, click on it an it will take you to your home directory. From there select the folder you want to have on the left hand side bar.

Comment: I appreciate the tips, but this feels clumsy and unsatisfying. I think geany will have a hard time catching on without the ability to just open a folder and get to work as people routinely do. Of course, it is open source, so I should really put my money where my mouth is and help with that.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the plugin "Project organizer". It's available together with a bunch of other plugins for Geany, get it by `apt-get install geany-plugins`.

With Project Organizer project creation works intuitive, you get a tree-view and code auto-completion reads every file in the project (not just the currently opened ones like it would otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

From the Terminal go to the directory you'd like to open, Type:

```
find . -name '*' -type f -exec geany  '{}' +
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `View` menu, choose `Show Sidebar`.

(Assuming you have already activated the `File Browser` plugin)